# how to deploy asp.net website in intranet- Copy paste folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, database-deployment

I am new to web developing and some how managed to create one web page with SQL database. Now I would like to deploy my website in localhost server by that users who are having access to that server can use the website. I did some search and deployed website in development computer by creating an application in IIS server `inetmgr`  however I don't know how to deploy in production system. Please guide me with possible and effective method by that I can proceed further.[Deployment to test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just to broad for SO. It sounds like you need to do some research and maybe read some tutorials. There are lots of guides for doing this exact thing using Microsoft development tools.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes i spent more time in locating exact article to follow but it ends up in confusion, please suggest me some useful links to follow

Comment: SO is not a good tutorial site. If you want help you need to tell us what research you have done, and the exact problem you are having. But as it stands, this is just not on topic for SO. To see why, you can take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Right-click your project, select Publish.

1. Create a profile name
2. On Connection tab, set the Deploy method to File System
3. Put the file location you want to publish to
4. On Settings tab, put in the database connection strings if necessary
5. Save
6. Right-click project, Publish
7. Go to the place where your site was published.
8. Copy all files in that folder and paste it in the IIS web server's virtual directory where your app will be located.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Owen, how could the database be accessed. I am using database first method

Comment: You need to have the connection string to the database and an EntityFramework context defined in your web.config.  I'm assuming your database exists remotely on the network.  While you could create a local db in  your project and publish that, I think you're much better off with the remote database.  I'll post an example tomorrow.